# Using matplotlib to plot Root objects obtained from Mathematica

Tags: python, matplotlib, wolfram-mathematica

I generated an analytical plot using Mathematica's ParametricPlot function which has `Root` objects and some Excel data I want to compare. I want to use `matplotlib` to plot them and not use Mathematica as shown in the code below.

```
epst1={{(3.1289-3.2317)/3.2317,0,0},{0,(2*5.0320-3*3.2317)/(3*3.2317),0},{0,0,(5.0320-5.1450)/5.1450}};
Ft=IdentityMatrix[3]+epst1*c;
Fe={{fe1,0,0},{0,fe2,0},{0,0,fe3}};
F=Fe . Ft
Sigma = {{1/2 ((1467 (1 - c))/10 + (1617 c)/10) (-1 + fe1^2) + 
   1/2 ((137 (1 - c))/2 + (363 c)/5) (-1 + fe2^2) + 
   1/2 (71 (1 - c) + (107 c)/2) (-1 + fe3^2), 0, 0}, {0, 
  1/2 ((137 (1 - c))/2 + (363 c)/5) (-1 + fe1^2) + 
   1/2 ((1467 (1 - c))/10 + (1617 c)/10) (-1 + fe2^2) + 
   1/2 (71 (1 - c) + (107 c)/2) (-1 + fe3^2), 0}, {0, 0, 
  1/2 (71 (1 - c) + (107 c)/2) (-1 + fe1^2) + 
   1/2 (71 (1 - c) + (107 c)/2) (-1 + fe2^2) + 
   1/2 ((1633 (1 - c))/10 + (978 c)/5) (-1 + fe3^2)}};
sbc = Solve[Sigma[[2,2]]==0&&Sigma[[3,3]]==0&&fe2>=1&&fe3>=1&&0<=c<=1,{fe2,fe3},Reals];

Eps={{0. + 0.5 (-1 + (1 - 0.0318099 c)^2) + (1 - 0.0318099 c) (0. + 
      0.5 (1 - 0.0318099 c) (-1 + fe1^2)), 0., 0.}, {0., 
  0. + 0.5 (-1 + (1 + 0.0380501 c)^2) + (1 + 0.0380501 c) (0. + 
      0.5 (1 + 0.0380501 c) (-1 + fe2^2)), 0.}, {0., 0., 
  0. + 0.5 (-1 + (1 - 0.0219631 c)^2) + (1 - 0.0219631 c) (0. + 
      0.5 (1 - 0.0219631 c) (-1 + fe3^2))}}

psi = 0.05159847372042989;
A=0.028631175092459882;
Xg3=3.175*^-3;
Wh10=Det[F]*Transpose[Fe] . ((Sigma . Inverse[Transpose[Fe]]) . Inverse[Ft]);
W10=epst1[[1,1]]*Wh10[[1,1]]+epst1[[2,2]]*Wh10[[2,2]]+epst1[[3,3]]*Wh10[[3,3]];
Xt=(W10-psi - A*(1-2*c)-3.175*^-3)/.{sbc[[1,1]],sbc[[1,2]]}//
Rationalize[#,0] &;

sxt=Solve[Xt==0&&0<=c<=1,fe1,Reals]

s11=Sigma[[1,1]]/.{sbc[[1,1]],sbc[[1,2]]};
e11=Eps[[1,1]];
plot2an=ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{-e11, -s11} /. sxt[[2]]], {c, 0, 1}, PlotStyle->{Black}, AspectRatio -> 1]


(*Combined analytical plot*)
plot1an=ListLinePlot[{{0,0},{0.025576025660634882`,2.6498102779298534`}}, PlotStyle->{Black}, AspectRatio -> 1]
plot3an=ParametricPlot[{-(-0.031303949003980314` +0.9681901166568678` (0.` +0.4840950583284339` (-1+fe1^2))),
-(80.85` (-1+fe1^2)+36.3` (-1+2.3712529512130725`*^-19 (5.879393604949724`*^18 -1.662213824579076`*^18 fe1^2))+
26.75` (-1+0.0005112474437627811` (3026.` -535.` fe1^2-1.2686203288989937`*^-16 (5.879393604949724`*^18 -1.662213824579076`*^18 fe1^2))))},
{fe1,0.96,0.9934428127813517`}, PlotStyle->{Black}, AspectRatio -> 1]
plotan=Show[plot1an,plot2an,plot3an, PlotRange->{{0,0.06},{0,5}}, PlotLegends->{"analytical"}, AspectRatio -> 1]


 data2num = Import["C:\\Users\\rnpra\\Box Sync\\Single crystal Zr\\Data\\1pbc_x\\combined_2.xlsx"];
 plotnum=ListLinePlot[{data2num[[1, All, {10, 16}]]},
 PlotLegends->{"8 elements"},AspectRatio->1]


plotcom=Show[plotan,plotnum,AspectRatio->1]
```

Just to clarify, the analytical plot is also a combination of three different plots `plot1an`, `plot2an` and `plot3an`. Of these, only `plot2an` has a `Root` object.

How can I transfer my analytical plot or the analytical expression from Mathematica to Python? Or is there a way I can use `matplotlib` inside of Mathematica, especially when dealing with `Root` objects?

[Here](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/fbccbbe3-3b6e-45d0-a4c0-63d24dd69f37) is the cloud version of the code I have written.
[Here](https://iastate.box.com/s/0mn418jpaz1jzu31wqp1ujtam5n50sm7) is the sample excel dataset.

Thanks in advance,
Raghunandan.

I looked at some other questions on the forum ([1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/180063/how-to-display-images-and-plots-from-externalevaluator#:%7E:text=import%20matplotlib%20matplotlib.use%20%28%27TkAgg%27%29%20%23%20doesn%27t%20work%20without,ax.set_title%20%28%27Plotting%20with%20Python%20inside%20Mathematica%27%29%20plt.show%20%28%29) and [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266451/how-to-use-python-functions-in-mathematica-functions-in-python-notebooks)), but none of these deal with `Root` objects.

Comment: If you carefully inspect `InputForm[{-e11,-s11}/.sxt[[2]]]` which makes up your `plot2an` then you should see that is made up of conditionals on polynomials in `c` times root number 7 (in the specific way that MMA numbers roots) of a 10th degree polynomial using 13th powers of c, and if that is not enough, ALL that is repeated 14 times to make up the complete expression that gives you your plot. I'm guessing that assuming Python will exactly reproduce that has probability 0.0*10^-lots.  If I do a Google search for `extract points from parametricplot` maybe you could get points to give  Python.